# Interprocess communication between Android and C#

Tags: c#, java, android, sockets

Attempting to perform sockets communication between Android and C# I seem to be stuck.

This is basically the code I have so far.

Android:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    try {
        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
        Socket mySocket = new Socket(serverAddr, 666);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

C#:

```
TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 666);
listener.Start();

using (Socket socket = listener.AcceptSocket())
{
    using (Stream stream = new NetworkStream(socket))
    {
    }
}
```

When hitting the line `Socket mySocket = new Socket(serverAddr, 666);` in my Android application I am getting the following error.

> "java.net.ConnectException:
>   localhost/127.0.0.1:666 - Connection
>   refused"

Anyone able to guide me as to what I am doing wrong?

PS: I am testing this through the emulator so wondering if there is possibly some sort of limitation about my ability to communicate with other processes running on the machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside the emulated machine the address 127.0.0.1 is not the host's loopback interface, it's the emulated machine's own loopback interface.

According to the [emulator documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking) you can access the host's loopback interface through the special address 10.0.2.2.

Comment: You're a gun. Spot on. My thinking was obviously crossed... Thank you!

Comment: Yay, points for an Android question! I knew that hoarding bookmarks to the docs of platforms I don't program in would come in handy sometime :P

Comment: lol, yeah I do the same thing. Go through moments of enthusiasm about a platform, research it and then something else takes your attention away!

Answer (score 2):

The exception details that you tried to connect to 127.0.0.1 from Android, this means your Android device. Since the server socket is on your Windows machine it cannot connect.